# SharePoint Document URL redirect

Tags: sharepoint

We have a SharePoint document library in our environment which has files in it. Extensions of all files in library is going to change to specific format. How can i do the URL redirect for files in IIS URL rewrite module, so when users access document with the old URL they should be navigated to to respective document which has new extension

Answer (score 0):

Try this as your rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="RedirectASPtoHTML" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
       <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^GET$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}.NEWEXTENSION{R:2}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```